# "Unfortunately,<App name> has stopped working" Pops up whenever i click a button

Tags: android, calculator, android-instant-run

I am trying to make a simple calculator using android studio. However when i click the button with text "1", the app crashes and the button with text "2" doesn't 
do anything. I have rightly added android:Onclick = "" to the xml. Please have a look at different source code files.

**PS: For now, I am trying to make the first two buttons work **

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.meenakshi.calculator.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_pressed"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:onClick="press1" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:text="@string/buttond_text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button4_text"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "@string/button2_text"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:onClick="press2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button3_text"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonmul_text"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button7_text"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button5_text"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button6_text"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button8_text"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonm_text"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button._text"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button0_text"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button9_text"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttone_text"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonp_text"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3" />
</GridLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.meenakshi.calculator;


import android.content.DialogInterface; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void press1(View v){

    edittext.setText("1");
}

public void press2(View v){

        edittext.setText("2");
  }





}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.meenakshi.calculator">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Stack trace**

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method press(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: StackTrace says press, xml you posted says press1

Comment: Can you send the project here as zip and I will fix it.

Comment: @Memme Thats what i have also been wondering. Earlier i used "press" everywhere and the stack trace was also showing "press". Later i changed "press" to "press1"  and stack trace still shows "press". Don't understand whats wrong with it.

Comment: Clean and rebuilt the project, or add it programmatically which I usually prefer anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that Activity has lifecycle and here we have following sequence of events:

- initialisation of fields <- here you initialised Button and EditText(at this moment there is no layout, so findViewById returns **null**)
- onCreate() <- here you inflating layout (after setContentView() you can find your views in layout)

---

Some recommendations:

Do not use onClick in xml - it makes it not obvious that something listens to onClick Event and in often (this case too) it is the root of problems. Use `findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener();` it makes that obvious.

onCreate() should be the method to initialise everything in your activity

**UPDATE**

In the end you would have something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        private EditText result;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
            findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button clickedBtn = (Button) v;
            switch (v.getId()){
                case (R.id.button1):
                case (R.id.button2):
                    result.append(clickedBtn.getText());
                    break;
                default:
                    //some other
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** it is better NOT to put numbers and signs to strings.xml - despite AS complains about that, but you will not reuse that in your program and there is no case about translating those strings :)

Comment: Your answer cleared a few of my concepts about what to do when,but it still doesn't solve the problem. I just used findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(); but to no avail.

Comment: I don't know what solved my problem. I, uninstalling the apk altogether  from my Genymotion virtual device and reinstalling it OR copying your entire code given above?. But now, yours as well as my alterations works magically fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);


}
```

Comment: If i do it like this it won't recognize edittext and btn in press1 and press2.

Comment: I just tried what you mentioned. Its not recognizing edittext and btn. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
EditText edittext;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call findViewById() after setContentView().
Calling

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);
```

outside any method will cause it to execute right in constructor which only Android system calls before calling onCreate() on instance on your activity. Which at that time will return null. Later in onCreate() method you are setting the content view for this activity

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

So please move those two lines after you call setContentView() in onCreate() method.

Comment: when i move the above two lines after "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);",Methods press1 and press2 doesn't recognze btn and edittext.

Comment: Declare the variables as class members

`Button mButton;
EditText mEditText;`

and then assign them in onCreate() after setContentView()

`mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); 
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);`